# How to count search results that depend on entered value in the textfields in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

I have 2 text fields (make, year) and class cars_new in parse cloud, how to count search results that depend on entered value in the textfields?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"cars_new"];
[query whereKey:@"make" equalTo:@"??"];
[query whereKey:@"year" equalTo:@"??"];


[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error){
    if(!error){
        NSLog(@"Count: %i", number);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to keep in mind that parse is really bad at counting objects. As soon as your table contains at least 1K objects, the result of the query is unpredictable:

> Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests per minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with more than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters, for example.)

[See the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-counting-objects)

Then, I supposed that by "entered value in the textfields" you are talking about 2 UITextField? If so, you can read their values by using the `text` attribute:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"cars_new"];
[query whereKey:@"make" equalTo:makeTextField.text];
[query whereKey:@"year" equalTo:yearTextField.text];
```